# Problema con has() dentro de un whereHas()

Tags: php, laravel

Buenas tardes, tengo un pequeño problema con una consulta, La tabla lapsos tiene asignadas muchas OfertasUba, en las cuales se inscriben muchos InscritosUba, una vez que a esos inscritos se le validan las notas (es decir, se pone el registro en la tabla de notas) no debe estar disponible esa oferta (o sección). La validación se realiza para todos los alumnos a la vez, así que quisiera hacer la consulta de modo que si alguno de los Inscritos ya posee registro en la tabla notas, se salte esa oferta, pero parece que el ->has() no esta funcionando, o no como espero, alguna ayuda?

El modelo de lapsos:

```
class Lapso extends Eloquent{

   protected $table = 'lapso';
    protected $primaryKey = 'lapso';

    protected $fillable = array('lapso', 'lapsoActual');

    public function ofertauba(){
      return $this->hasMany('OfertaUba','lapso');
    }

}
```

El modelo de ofertas:

```
class OfertaUba extends Eloquent{

  protected $table = 'oferta_uba';
  protected $fillable = array('curso', 'nucleo', 'lapso', 'regimen', 'modalidad', 'turno', 'aula', 'dias', 'horas', 'cupos', 'facilitador', 'fecha_inicio', 'fecha_fin', 'fecha_apertura','fecha_cierre');

   public function inscritosuba(){
       return $this->hasMany('InscritosUba','id_oferta')->orderBy('cedula','asc');
   }

   public function facilitadores(){
       return $this->belongsTo('Facilitadores','facilitador');
   }

   public function modalidades(){
       return $this->belongsTo('Modalidad','modalidad');
   }

   public function nucleos(){
       return $this->belongsTo('Nucleos','nucleo');
   }

   public function niveles(){
       return $this->belongsTo('Niveles','curso','Nivel');
   }

   public function regimenes(){
       return $this->belongsTo('Regimen','regimen');
   }

    public function lapsos(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Lapso','lapso');
    }
}
```

Aqui esta el modelo de inscritos:

```
 class InscritosUba extends Eloquent{

   protected $table = 'inscritos_uba';

   protected $fillable = array('cedula', 'curso', 'id_oferta', 'correo', 'telefono','pregunta_asocim','detalle_asocim');

   public function ofertauba(){
      return $this->belongsTo('OfertaUba','id_oferta');
   }

   public function estudiante(){
      max_execution_time();
      return $this->belongsTo('Estudiantes','cedula');
   }

   public function pagosuba(){
      return $this->hasMany('PagosUba','id_inscrito');
   }

    public function notaFinal(){
      max_execution_time();
      return $this->hasOne('Notas','CEDULA','cedula')->where('lapso','=',$this->ofertauba->lapso);
    }
}
```

El modelo de notas:

```
class Notas extends Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'notas';
    protected $fillable = array('CEDULA','LAPSO','NRO','NOTA','COD_MAT','SECCION','ORD_LAP','CORTE1','CORTE2','STATUS','COD_NUC');
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = null;
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function nucleos(){
       return $this->belongsTo('Nucleos','COD_NUC');
    }
}
```

Aqui esta la consulta:

```
public function postObtenerSecciones(){
  $curso = Input::get('curso');
  $nucleo = Input::get('nucleo');
  $lapso = Input::get('lapso');
  $secciones = OfertaUba::select('id','curso','lapso','nucleo','seccion')
    ->where('curso','=',$curso)
    ->where('nucleo','=',$nucleo)
    ->where('lapso','=',$lapso)
    ->whereHas('inscritosuba', function($query){
      $query->has('notaFinal','<',1);
    })
    ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberías utilizar

```
$query->where('notaFinal','<',1);
```

en vez de la línea:

```
$query->has('notaFinal','<',1);
```

Comment: Hola @bafdurango. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Gracias por el aporte, pero como el nombre del sitio te indica, tu respuesta debería estar en español. Además, ¿podrías explicar por qué se debería hacer este cambio y cómo es que esto solucionaría a todo el problema de la pregunta?

Comment: notaFinal es una relacion, no un campo, por eso uso el has